# Space where the separation theorem doesn't hold

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

I have read the proof of the next separation theorem:
Let X b a normed space in R and A a convex and open set that contains 0. Let b be a point wich is not in A then there exists f in X* such that f(a)<1 for all a in A and f(b)=1.

I am asked to look for a normed space X and a convex subspace A that contains 0 and a point b which is not in A such that it DOESN'T EXIST any function f in X* such that f(a)<1 for all a in A and f(b)=1.

So I have to find explicit X, A, and b. Also I see that maybe the trick is that A is not open in the exercise.
Any help? Thank you!! :)

Answer (score 0):

If the subspace $A$ is not closed it is possible.

For example let $X=\ell^2(\mathbb N)$, and $A$ the subspace of all sequences which eventually vanish - $a=(a_n)\in A$ if there exists an $n_0$, such that $a_k=0$, for all $k\ge n_0$, and let $b=(\frac{1}{n^2})_{n\in\mathbb B}\not\in A$. Clearly $A$ is dense in $X$.

$A$ is also convex, as $a,b\in A$, and $a$ vansihes after $k$, $b$ vanishes after $\ell$, then every linear combination of them vanishes after $\max\{k,\ell\}$.

If $f$ is a continuous functional, with $f(x)<1$, on $A$, then $f(x)=0$ on $A$. For if $f(x)=s\ne 0$, for some $x\in A$, then $f(x/s)=1$ and $x/s\in A$. Clearly if $f$ vanishes on a dense subset of $X$, it has to vanish on $X$, and hence $f(b)=0$.